# Can undead be frightened?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, conditions, immunities

So in a campaign as a paladin, I cast Wrathful Smite and hit an undead creature. Can undead be affected by the frightened condition?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get a chance.

Answer (score 22):

#### Some yes, some no. And it's a surprisingly-even split.

There's no general rule on undead: either the Frightened condition (PHB Appendix A) or the Monster Manual's section on undead (MM pp.6-7, "Types") would be the places to look. But each specific undead's stat-block describes whether it is immune to the Frightened condition. ([Is there any reason to why the list of undead that can be frightened seems counter intuitive?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78525/23970) addresses the "why" of this.)

For reference, the MM has the following Undead which...

**cannot be frightened:**

> Banshee, Death Knight, various Liches, Flameskull, Ghost, Mummy and Mummy Lord, Revenant, and Shadow.

**can be frightened:**

> Death Tyrant, Crawling Claw, Ghast, Ghoul, Bone Naga, various Skeletons, Specter, Wight, Will-o'-Wisp, Wraith, and various Zombies.

Answer (score 8):

There's no rule that states undead *in general* are immune to being frightened so it depends on what *specific* undead creature you're attacking.

Some undead do have immunity to the frightened condition while others don't.

A banshee, for example, is immune to being frightened so if you were to hit one with wrathful smite, it would only take the damage and be unaffected by the condition.

Whereas a skeleton or zombie is not immune to being frightened so it would take the full force of a wrathful smite.